# how to add protractor locator for add click function in this menu

Tags: protractor

I have two menus '`Setup`' and '`Reports`' with sub-menus '`admin users`','`Reports dashboard`','`partner dashboard`','`partner relationship`' etc marked with red color.

[image]

I want to navigate or click using protractor locators but unable to find how to select these menus that have no id and common CSS. I want something like this

```
var userTypes = element.all(by.repeater('t in user_userTypes'));</br>
userTypes.get(2).click()
```

Comment: It's easier to help if you post your html as a code block instead of an image.

Comment: I have attached the html code in http://1strackcourier.com/protractor.txt    ...... Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see, these elements are navigation menu items, `Setup` and `Reports` are high-level menus and `Admin Users`, `Reports Dashboard`, `Partner dashboard`, `Partner Relationship` and `Grading Data` are submenus. To open a submenu, I assume, you should click the appropriate menu.

Let's make a reusable function that would accept a *menu label and a desired submenu label* and use [`by.repeater()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.repeater) locator [filtering](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter) the menus *by text*:

```
function selectMenu(menuLabel, submenuLabel) {
    var menu = element.all(by.repeater("mi in menuItems")).filter(function (menu) {
        return menu.all(by.tagName("a")).first().getText().then(function (text) {
            return text.indexOf(menuLabel) === 0;
        });
    }).first();

    menu.click();  // open up menu

    var submenu = menu.all(by.repeater("s in mi.subMenuItems")).filter(function (submenu) {
        return submenu.all(by.tagName("a")).first().getText().then(function (text) {
            return text.indexOf(submenuLabel) === 0;
        });
    }).first();

    submenu.click();  // select submenu
}
```

Usage samples:

```
selectMenu("Setup", "Admin Users");
selectMenu("Reports", "Reports Dashboard");
```

Comment: I have tried this but an error found this Failed: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index:
only 0 elements that match locator by.repeater("mi in menuItems

Comment: @Ranjancode okay, updated the answer - replaced the equality check with "starts-with" check.

Comment: I didn't understand where to replace it

Comment: @Ranjancode I have updated the code in the answer, try it.

Comment: I couldn't found your updated answer. Please help... I am in a trouble

Answer (score 1):

Define a method and pass the 'hrefValue', filter by anchor tag.

```
 var clickParticular = function(hrefValue){
          element.all(by.tagName('a')).filter(function(element, index) {
              return element.getAttribute('href').then(function (text) {
                  return text === hrefValue;
              });
          }).then(function(filteredElements) {
              filteredElements[0].click().then(function() {
              });
          });
      }
```

Comment: how to call this function. I am very new in protractor

Comment: call by name: clickParticular('passParticularHrefValue');